# spark-submit custom jar on kubernetes fails with: failed to load class

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I cannot run a custom Spark application on Kubernetes.

I have followed the setup https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html and the steps on examplel like these: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-spark-from-source-and-deploy-it-to-a-kubernetes-cluster-in-60-minutes-225829b744f9  and I can run the spark-pi example.

I even recreated the spark image and have it contain my xxx.jar in both /opt/spark/examples/jars and /opt/spark/jars  but still I get the failed to load class issue. Any ideas what I may have missed. This is extra baffling to me because I checked that the jar is part of the image right next to the example jars, and those work fine.

I run spark-submit like this.

```
bin/spark-submit
--master k8s://https://localhost:6443
--deploy-mode cluster
--conf spark.executor.instances=3
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=spark2:latest
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=Never
--class com.xxx.Application
--name myApp
local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/xxx.jar
```

Update: Added stacktrace:

```
spark.driver.bindAddress=10.1.0.68 --deploy-mode client --properties-     file /opt/spark/conf/spark.properties --class com.xxx.Application    local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/xxx.jar

20/05/13 11:02:09 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Error: Failed to load class com.xxx.Application.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager).
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Verify the jar which you referring has `Application.class` file at `com.xxx.Application.class` using `jar xf <jar name>.jar`
Replace

```
local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/xxx.jar
```

with

```
/opt/spark/examples/jars/xxx.jar
```

in your `spark-submit` command

Comment: If I do that I get:

    Exception in thread “main” org.apache.spark.SparkException: Please specify spark.kubernetes.file.upload.path property.

Comment: I was able to pass my application jar as ```mainApplicationFile: "/opt/spark/classpath/json-to-parquet-0.1.jar"``` using yml file

Comment: Are you sure your jar which you referring has Application.class file at com.xxx.Application.class path ? You might want to extract it and verify

Comment: I am sure. Already extracted it. The class is there, the package names are proper. I don't see any naming or location issue.

Comment: Have you verified it by logging into your Driver / executor pod that its not using any cached version of your jar file.

Comment: No because the pods fail due to the error I mentioned previously.

Comment: How do you build your jar? Just to be sure that jar is built correctly you can try to run Spark with master local[*] before submitting to Kubernetes. You can do that by running the shell in Spark container: `docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash spark-image:your-tag`.